# Edit trackbar value while paused

Tags: c++, opencv

In the code below I've created a loop which keeps running till 'q' is pressed. I'm using trackbars to set 2 variables. However I want to create some sort of pause to set these trackbars before running through this loop. The getch() function however, freezes the entire program until I press a keyand doesn't allow me to edit the trackbars. Is it possible to create some sort of pause which does allow me to edit the trackbars?

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    cvNamedWindow("test image", CV_WINDOWS_AUTOSIZE);
    cvCreateTrackbar("subject", "test image", &subjectID, 40, NULL);
    cvCreateTrackbar("subject", "test image", &photoID, 10, NULL);
    ...
    <some more code>
    ...

    while(key != 'q')
    {
        cout << "set trackbars and press enter";
        getch()
        ...
        <and more code>
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another while loop and cv::waitKey() should do the trick.

```
cout << "set trackbars and press enter"; //you might want to put this inside the loop
while (true) {
            int c = waitKey(10);
            if( c == 13) { break; } 
        }

while(key != 'q')
{
    ...
    /*all your code*/
    ...
}
```

Comment: Mja ofcourse :p why trying it the hard way when I implemented the solution already. Only had to extend it like you suggested ^^, thanks anyways